# What is the use of an empty interface without methods?

Tags: java, interface

What is the use of an empty interface without methods?

For example:

```
interface One {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

These are called [Marker Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) and it's one of the design pattern.

Classes implementing these interfaces possess special behaviors as per the definition of the interface.

For Example: A class which implements marker interface `Serializable` can be serialized.

Now a days these are replaced by [Annotations](https://sites.google.com/site/wagingguerillasoftware/marker-interfaces-vs-annotations)

Answer (score 2):

They're referred to as [marker interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern). They can imply various things about an implementing class beyond the existence of certain methods, such as the use of certain annotations, or most commonly that the class is capable of being serialized.

Answer (score 2):

This can be used to mark the class of being "something" on that certain approaches make sense. For instance, implementing Serializable interface says that the given instance object of this class can be reconstructed by assigning its fields to the previous values.

Answer (score 2):

An example of a Marker interface without any methods is:

```
public interface Serializable {
}
```

A class implements this interface to indicate that its non-transient data members can be written to an ObjectOutputStream.

used with languages that provide run-time type information about objects. It provides a means to associate metadata with a class where the language does not have explicit support for such metadata.